# Function To Convert Data Type of Multiple Columns in R

Tags: r, function, type-conversion, data-science

I have a data frame here like this:

| segment_order | insight_group | index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | male | "1.25" |
| 2 | female | "3.25" |
| 3 | family | "5.25 |

I wish to convert the data type of the `index` column is char data type. This is pretty easy to do with the `as.numeric(as.character())`

However because I would have to write this same line of code 10+ times I'm trying to write a function that intakes the dataframe and then mutates the column type from char to numeric. After multiple tries, I have tried

```
indexvariable.cleanup <- function(df){
  
  mutate(across(ends_with("_index")),as.numeric)
  )
  #return(data.frame(df))
}
```

But the `[2]` has to be an input. Other times I tried to intake two variables into the function, the dataframe and vect but the output would be a new column onto the dataframe which I do not want.

Comment: Add the `df %>%` before the `mutate`

Comment: `mutate(df, across(ends_with("_index")),as.numeric)`